# Why all pop-up windows can't appear on ROS diamondback?

Tags: qt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, all.

Currently I am using "joint_state_publisher" node and "dynamic_configuration" node.

The pop-up window **doesn't appear** on my laptop but **appear** on my desktop.

The exact same code well works on my desktop which has Qt 4.7.0 and Qmake version 2.0.1a. Python 2.6.6 Ubuntu10.04, ROS diamondback 1.4.6.

My laptop also has has Qt 4.7.0 and Qmake version 2.0.1a. Python 2.6.6 Ubuntu10.04, ROS diamondback 1.4.6.

Is there anyone who encounter this problem?

Thank you for reading.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9994/why-all-pop-up-windows-can%27t-appear-on-ros-diamondback?/) by [enddl22](https://answers.ros.org/users/194/enddl22/) on ROS Answers with karma: 177 on 2011-05-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Solved!.

The problem was on apt-get diamondback installation.

I installed diamondback through apt-get and something was wrong.
(I have still no idea whats the problem)

Anyway by installing diamondback through source install, "dynamic_configuration" and "joint_state_publisher" is working now.

I hope this is going to help someone.

Cheers.

---

Originally posted by [enddl22](https://answers.ros.org/users/194/enddl22/) with karma: 177 on 2011-05-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0